# There is no connection tag from Admin menu on Airflow web UI

Tags: airflow

I'm using admin user to log in. But, there is only Variables this tag inside.

My Airflow Version is 1.10.3

[image: d]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you create the airflow user?

I'm guessing you are not a superuser. Airflow supports standard and superuser when not using RBAC.

I would recommend you to create a new user using python shell.

```
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
user = PasswordUser(models.User())
user.username = 'nitin'
user.email = 'nitinl@example.com'
user.password = 'nitin'
user.superuser = True
session = settings.Session()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
exit()
```